# Fill an array in php with two array

Tags: php

I have two numeric arrays (these arrays will always have the same number of keys and values).

```
$array1 = array(0 => "key1", 1 => "key2");
$array2 = array(0 => "value1", 1 => "value2");
$array_final = array(value of the $array1 => $value of the array2);
```

If I write a while and fill the `$array_final`, it only fills with the last key and value

So it's like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array(1))
{
    $array_final = array($array1[$i] => $array2[$i]);
}
$array_final = array("key2" => "value2");
```

But I want:

```
$array_final = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
```

Comment: You mean you want to have 2 identical indexes in one array? No its impossible.

Comment: Look at array_combine

Comment: You are overwriting your array each time in the loop, look an Majid L solution. That's how to add the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

It does exatcly what you need

So basically

```
$array1 = array(0 => "key1", 1 => "key2");
$array2 = array(0 => "value1", 1 => "value2");

$array_final = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0; $i< sizeof($array1) &&  $i< sizeof($array2) ; $i++)
{
  $array_final[$array1[$i]] =$array2[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thx that's work fine but the method with array_combine takes less lines ;) !

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code.

```
       $array1 = array(0 => "key1", 1 => "key2");
       $array2 = array(0 => "value1", 1 => "value2");
       $array_final = combine_if_same_keys($array1,$array2);
       print_r($array_final);


       function combine_if_same_keys( $array_one, $array_two ) {

         $expected = false;

          ksort($array_one);
          ksort($array_two);

         $diff = array_diff_key($array_one, $array_two);
         if( empty($diff) && count($array_one) == count($array_two) ) {
             $expected = array_combine( $array_one, $array_two );
         }

          return $expected;
       }
```